# *** glibc detected *** free(): invalid pointer

Tags: c++, pointers, pthreads, free, glibc

I have the following code that produces a `*** glibc detected *** free(): invalid pointer` error whenever I run the code.

`main.h`:

```
#ifndef PTHREAD_CALC_H_
#define PTHREAD_CALC_H_

void* task(void*);

#endif
```

`main.cxx`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include "main.h"

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

    pthread_t *threads = (pthread_t*)malloc(sizeof(pthread_t)*2);
    double  *temp;

    double sum = 0.0;
    for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
        pthread_create(&(threads[j]), NULL, task, NULL);
    }

    for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
        pthread_join(threads[j], (void**)(&temp));
        sum += *temp;
    }

    free(threads);
    free(temp);

    return 0;
}

void* task(void *data) {
    double sum = 5;
    pthread_exit((void*)&sum);
    return NULL;
}
```

I'm having a hard time determining what is causing the error.  Any assistance is greatly appreciated.  If I can provide anything else to help pinpoint the problem, please let me know.

Thank you

**Edit**

For sake of completion, here is the resulting code that executes as expected:

`main.cxx`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include "main.h"

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

    pthread_t *threads = (pthread_t*)malloc(sizeof(pthread_t)*2);
    double  *temp;

    double sum = 0.0;
    for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
        pthread_create(&(threads[j]), NULL, task, NULL);
    }

    for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
        pthread_join(threads[j], (void**)&temp);
        sum += temp;
        delete temp;
    }

    free(threads);
    return 0;
}

void* task(void *data) {
    double* sum = new double;
    *sum = 5.0;
    pthread_exit(static_cast<void*>(sum));
}
```

Comment: Unrelated, but you are passing back a reference to sum out of task, but sum is on the stack. This variable may not exist when you add it to the sum variable in main.

Comment: @MWB isn't that the point of `pthread_join()`? It blocks the parent thread until the task is complete.  This leads me to believe `sum` should exist and it's value should be in stored in `temp`

Comment: From the man page (http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_exit.3.html)

  The value pointed to by retval should not be located on the calling thread's stack, since the contents of that stack are undefined after the thread terminates.

Comment: @MWB I see what you mean know.  Thank you for pointing this out.

Comment: @AlexBrooks You don't allocate with `new` the memory for sum after your edit.

Comment: @hetepeperfan Thank you for catching; forgot to switch over the correction.  Fixed.

Comment: The working solution in your edit leaks memory, namely one `double` per thread run.

Comment: @alk Updated to prevent the memory leak.

Comment: The `delete(temp);` should go into the loop around `pthread_join()` as there is one `new` per thread, there shall be one `delete` per thread either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently your thread task returns some value on the stack of the thread. When the thread finishes there is no guarantee that *temp will point to something valid.

Thus after this call

```
pthread_join(threads[j], (void**)(&temp));
```

temp points to the old location of sum in the thread, but if the thread finishes it doesn't exists anymore. And using it will result in undefined behavior.

yet later you free temp which points to the double on the other stack, but there is noting to free since stack allocations are free automatically when they go out of scope.

```
free(temp);
```

want you might want to do is:

```
void* task(void *data) {
    double* sum = new double;
    *sum = 5;
    pthread_exit(static_cast<void*>(sum) );
}
```

and then in main after joining the thread

```
delete temp;
```

Comment: With your help, I have found a solution.  I will update the original post to contain code that produces expected behaviour.

Comment: @AlexBrooks Glad to be of help but you shouldn't change your code in you post so much, it makes it hard to keep updating my answer when you keep updating your question.

Comment: Certainly.  I just didn't want people to complain that the code was too long.  I should have waited to post until I had produced the shorten code.  I will keep this in mind for next time.

Comment: Oh on the side note I used C++ new don't mix it with free, used delete as I mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

In your code you declare:

```
double  *temp;
```

You never malloc to the address, but later you free it.  This will produce the error.  Remove the free(temp) and it should work.  Actually though you've introduced new errors by dereferencing *temp without storage.

Comment: Wow I feel dumb... I don't know how I missed that.  Thank you.  Now I just need to figure out how to get the sum value into `temp`...

Comment: This is not enough as MWB point out in the comments above. This as currently describes will result in undefined behavior since *temp will point to a variable on the threads stack.

Comment: Right.  OP's code changed a few times between my posts.  IIRC, the original post did actually malloc for temp but freed it in task() and at the end of the program.  Anyways, the selected answer is correct for the current code given.